# Convert string to JSON valid format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, regex

I'm receiving response data from external service and need to parse received string. Issue is, that some string keys/values are using `'` instead of `"`. First solution I've tried was to use gsub and just replace all `'` with `"` but than I've received another issue - some response values contains `'` as word separator and it looks like this -
`"{'text': \"Hi there-Thanks for writing in. Unfortunately, I don't\"}"`, so when I'm replacing `'` JSON still is not valid.
What I need to convert this to valid format, like -
`"{\"text\": \"Hi there-Thanks for writing in. Unfortunately, I don't\"}"`

Comment: It would help a lot if you would write a code example of input, your function, output. To convert a JSON string to an object, I'd go for: `obj = JSON.parse(string)` and then to convert is back to a string: `JSON.pretty_generate(obj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why those responses cannot be parsed as JSON is because they are not JSON strings. It's not an issue of "replacing" quotes, those strings have missing quotes which are critical to JSON parsing.

Here's how they should look to be easily parsed:

```
x = {text: "Hi there-Thanks for writing in. Unfortunately, I don't"}.to_json 
# => "{\"text\":\"Hi there-Thanks for writing in. Unfortunately, I don't\"}"
JSON.parse(x) # should work ok
```

What you could do is to try with `YAML.load`:

```
y = "{'text': \"Hi there-Thanks for writing in. Unfortunately, I don't\"}"
YAML.load(y)

z = "{\"text\": \"Hi there-Thanks for writing in. Unfortunately, I don't\"}"
YAML.load(z)
```

It works for those 2 strings but not sure how the other responses look like.